# Can I use bootstrap with the Mudblazor controls?

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

My apps all use bootstrap 5 css framework, and I'd rather not change that.  If I want to use MudBlazor can I get away from materialize and still use bootstrap?

Comment: the problem is mostly with bootstrap.js file.  if you need only styles you can add only bootstrap.css file to your _layout.cshtml or index.htlm. that is the way Radzen solving that problem. it can help consider it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Bootstrap with MudBlazor controls
add bootstap cdn link into `index.cshtm;` or `index.html`

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```